# Can't Connect To MySQL (Openshift)

Tags: php, mysqli, openshift

I can't connect to MySQL on Openshift. There is nothing wrong in the parameter, but it doesn't want to connect.

```
$link = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1","user","password","database") or die("Error" . mysqli_error($link));
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question seems is a bit a bit vague, but assuming you have a Openshift PHP application and want to connect to a Openshift MySQL cartridge, then you should not use hard coded IP addresses. Instead there is a whole range of [environment variables](https://developers.openshift.com/en/databases-mysql.html) which define the required properties, e.g. `OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST`. You need to use these variables. Using PHP you can read an environment variable like this:

```
$database_host = getenv('OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST');
```

Comment: Yes, I should use that :)
Thank you kindly, Sir.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the environment variables to connect to your database, you can read more about them here (https://developers.openshift.com/en/databases-mysql.html), also, what is the error that is being displayed when your connection does not work?

Comment: Yes, I should use that :)
Thank you kindly, Sir.

Answer (score 0):

I was having this issue when I was working with Angular JS earlier. When I would try to connect to the port 8080, I would get a connection error. After looking around online, I used port 3306 and that connected just fine.

I would recommend specifying a port to connect to. You can try the below line of code to see if it works.

`mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1","user","password","database", 3306)`

Comment: I use the wrong IP Address, I should've use from the environment variable :)